# Can't figure out the cause of BAD_ACCESS error?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, struct

When trying to initialize this vector with "Cell"'s, a bad access error keeps getting thrown at

```
grid.emplace_back(Cell{1,false, row,col});
```

And I can't seem to figure out why. After some googling I believe it has something to do with memory getting dereferenced or lost, but can't seem to figure out where exactly this is happening. Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks.

```
struct Cell{
    int cellVal;
    bool visited;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
};
vector<vector<Cell>> grid;
vector<Cell> path(15);

vector<Cell> monsterPath(15);
int main() {

    grid.reserve(15);
    for(int row = 0; row <=1; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col <=15; col++){
            grid[col].reserve(15);
            grid.emplace_back(Cell{1,false,row,col});
        }
    }
```

Thanks to @user0042 the above code segment no longer throws the bad access error. However, my next code segments throws the exact same error, specifically the first line in the if statement.

```
if((!grid[path[curX].xPos - 1][path[curX].yPos].visited) &&       //cell being checked is (x-1, y)
               !grid[path[path.size() - 1].xPos - 1][path[path.size() - 1].yPos - 1].visited &&              //check cell x-1, y-1
               !grid[path[path.size() - 1].xPos - 2][path[path.size() - 1].yPos].visited &&                  //check cell x-2, y
               !grid[path[path.size() - 1].xPos][path[path.size() + 1].yPos + 1].visited)                //check cell x, y+1
            {
                grid[path[path.size()-1].xPos - 1][path[path.size()-1].yPos].cellVal = 0;
                grid[path[path.size()-1].xPos - 1][path[path.size()-1].yPos].visited = true;
                path.emplace_back((grid[path[path.size()-1].xPos - 1][path[path.size()-1].yPos]));
                cout << "path constructed" << endl;

            }
```

Comment: Use `resize()` instead of `reserve()`.

Comment: @user0042 would using the assignment operator instead of emplace_back make a difference as well? Thanks by the way

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: Genius, thanks. How did I not think of this before???? /s

Answer (score 0):

The line

for(int col = 0; col <=15; col++)

seems wrong, as the highest element you can index is 14, not 15. You should replace the <= with a <.

For your other piece of code, I don't know what's the content of curX, xPos, curY and yPos, but make sure they are not bigger then your array size - 1.